# Drupal: Views taxonomy exposed filter, show tree/hierarchy in drop down menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, taxonomy

I have an exposed taxonomy filter that allows the user the filter by term. The vocabulary is 2 tiers, however in the exposed filter menu the hierarchy appears flat.

Is there a method/module to show the hierarchy with indentation or prefixing child terms with "-", similar to the taxonomy term selection menu from the node edit form itself.

x-post from https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4578/views-taxonomy-exposed-filter-show-tree-hierarchy-in-drop-down-menu

SOLUTION:

The filter Taxonomy: Term ID (with Depth) will display the option "Show Hierarchy In Dropdown" when you select the Dropdown widget.

Comment: Not quite the behaviour you're after but I find http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select works quite well.

Comment: You should answer your question with the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter Taxonomy: Term ID (with Depth) will display the option "Show Hierarchy In Dropdown" when you select the Dropdown widget.